# Macro that dynamically defines record based on protocol

Tags: clojure

My goal is to create a macro such that `(defdummy MyProtocol MyImplementation)` will create a record type as `defrecord` does.  It would also be acceptable to just generate an implementation of `MyProtocol` like `reify` does.  This record type should implement all methods of the given protocol, but just return `nil` for each method.  e.g:

```
(defprotocol Annoying
  (beep [x] "Make a sound"))

;; This form...    
(defdummy Annoying FakeAnnoyer)

;; Should expand to this
(defrecord FakeAnnoyer []
  Annoying
  (beep [x] nil))
```

I see that when we evaluate the protocol, we have some methods that can be used to generate the implementations of the protocol methods: `:sigs`, `:arglists`, etc.  However, because macros receive their arguments unevaluated, I can't access this information from inside the macro.  If a macro user passes a protocol `MyProtocol` to my macro, I just see the symbol `'MyProtocol`.  It seems to me that this information is statically known at compile time, but I don't know if I can find it out when generating protocol methods.

The only way that I can think of is either to use `eval` or to expand to some of the inner workings of `defrecord`.  Is there any other way?

Comment: It seems that `schema.core/defrecord` takes the path of duplicating some of the mechanism of `defrecord`.

Comment: what is the purpose of this? where should the FakeAnnoyer#beep implementation come from - or does it return always `nil` ? bacause then you'll probably want [extend-protocol](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/extend-protocol) with a "nil catch all" clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`resolve`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve) function. For instance, here is a basic implementation of your `defdummy` macro:

```
(defmacro defdummy [protocol record]
  `(defrecord ~record []
     ~protocol
     ~@(for [[_ {:keys [name arglists]}] (:sigs @(resolve protocol))]
         `(~name ~@arglists nil))))
```

Example:

```
(defprotocol Annoying
  (beep [x] "Make a sound"))

(macroexpand-1 '(defdummy Annoying FakeAnnoyer))
;;=> (clojure.core/defrecord FakeAnnoyer [] Annoying (beep [x] nil))
```